# Converting string to unknown primitive type (best guess)

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, string-parsing

Obviously this isn't something you would want to do unless you're in a helpless situation, but does anyone have a good example of something like this (bonus points for thinking of a clearer method name):

```
public static object ConvertToBestGuessPrimitive(string toConvert)
{
    if(looksLikeAnInt)
    {
        return as an int;
    }
    else if(looksLikeABoolean)
    {
        return as a boolean;
    }
    else
    {
        return as a string;
    }
}
```

The only idea I had was to chain together a bunch of TryParse methods together in a sensible order and fall back to string if nothing works. Can anyone think of something better? This question has probably already been answered somewhere, but I can't seem to find any useful results with the overly generic search terms being used.

Edit - Since there's been some criticism of how useful this would be without an example, here's one I came up with to satisfy a concrete need (however implausible)...Say I am parsing an error log file that I get from an uncontrolled source. The log file has method names and arguments that were provided for where the error occurred. I want to automate testing the error conditions by finding the best matched method and arguments and attempting to call them again. Maybe a stupid example (please don't try and come up with "but you could do this in this scenario" responses since this is just an example), but it illustrates a few points: 1) The input is out of my control. 2) The best-guess is based on some criteria for finding a suitable match. For example: a "10/2/2012" is more likely to mean a DateTime than a string.

Comment: Why not then Declare that Method as Dynamic if not I would do a Switch statement also where are you even checking of using `toConvert` `Method name come on now you should be smart enough to come up with a Method name that describes what you are doing or trying to do for example `ConvertToPrimitiveType`

Comment: I don't get it. How would you use this method? How can it be useful?

Comment: I agree with @nmat. Maybe you can show us an example of where you'd like to use it.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with something like a poorly designer 3rd party software or web service I see no need whatsoever to have something like this in your code.

Comment: Somehow I knew that even with my, "obviously", and "in a helpless situation" comments that I would get these responses, haha. Can't a guy just ask a question out of curiosity? I don't even *have* a direct use case, but surely you can at least *imagine* up something that would require this (like HighCore did).

Comment: But anything looks like a string.

Comment: @Ocelot20 This is something that you almost assuredly shouldn't be doing, * particularly* if you don't already have a use case that you even think is valid.  If you're just looking to learn more about the language and become a better programmer there are much more things you can learn about that will actually be useful.

Comment: @Ocelot20 I am asking because I don't see how the output of that method can be useful. Since you don't know the return type wouldn't you need another if else block to deal with the returned object? That defeats the original purpose.

Comment: @nmat: It still returns an object that has a Type though. See my edit for a concrete-ish example.

Answer (score 1):

So you're looking to get rid of if-elses? What about something like this:

```
interface IConverter
{
  bool TryConvert(string obj, out object result);
}

class IntConvert : IConverter
{
  public bool TryConvert(string obj, out object result) { /* stuff here */ }
}

class BoolConverter : IConverter {...}

// etc.
List<IConverter> converters = new List<IConverter>();
converters.Add(new IntConvert());
converters.Add(new BoolConvert());

public static object ConvertToBestGuessPrimitive(string toConvert)
{
  object obj;
  foreach(var converter in converters) {
    if(converter.TryConvert(toConvert, out obj))
       return obj;
  }

  return null;
}
```

UPDATE: Thanks Servy for the suggestion.

Comment: You're parsing each string twice with a check and then convert method; it's probably better to combine them into a TryParse method.

Comment: definitely agree. thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, trying to parse is the most sound way because parsing is culture-specific. If you just ask the .NET Framework to parse you will adhere to the current culture settings automatically. This is in contrast to a manual parsing approach (potentially based on a Regex).

Also, I don't know of any string which can be interpreted ambiguously among bool, int, float and DateTime. (with the obvious exception that any int is also a float, so parse for int first).

A better name would be `ConvertToBestGuessPrimitiveType`. I added "Type".